# How do I begin to lay out floor tile in a small bathroom?

Tags: floor, tiling

I have a small bathroom 58x52 
Do I need to start in center of room 
Can I start on wall. Less cutting. 
How do I make sure tile is square on the floor in case wall is not plumb.

Tile is 12x12.   6pcs across 4 pcs down.

Comment: If "58x52" (which I missed on first reading) is inches, it's 5 (12-inch) tiles by 5 tiles (since 4-and-a-third tiles is 5 tiles in the tile-buying stage, and 3+more-than-a-half on each side in the tile-laying phase. That is another part of the "normal" reason - avoiding "slivers" or very narrow tiles at the edge. 5X12 is 60 inches, so 58 inches is also "3+more-than-a-half on each side"

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a very small bathroom I tend to lay the tile out on the doorway, where the pattern and position are most conspicuous. I usually center either a tile or a joint. In the case of 12" tiles this is even more impactful, as an off-center doorway catches the eye.

Then, lay out tiles in both directions and see how they interact with walls, plumbing fixtures, and cabinetry.

Almost any project should be undergone with this approach--ask yourself what will be seen and noticed most often, and make compromises where necessary to fulfill that goal. In this case, the number of cuts you have to make for a project intended to last many years is irrelevant.

Comment: I agree with this, what is important is how it will look to you and others, not what is "correct" or "normal". One thing I will stress is that you are careful to split distances as implied by @Ecnerwal. You do not want to end up with a thin strip of tile along one wall unless it will be hidden well.

Answer (score 1):

You can start wherever you like - there are consequences, though.

The reason for normally starting in the middle of the floor is that walls are often (always...) NOT straight or square, and thus a better job results from starting in the center and trimming ALL the walls, rather than starting along one or two walls. Thus, for a "4x6" room, you'd have 3 full tiles by 5 full tiles and trim half tiles (which you might be able to use both halves of, depending on exact size of the room) for every wall contact; that's following normal tiling procedures.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to start in the center is to make the room look even. By measuring each end then putting a line down the center you will be able to follow that and any out of square errors are cut in half. The molding/ mop board will help hide the edges. If you want to start from 1 wall pick the wall that has the largest view from the door and go from there would be my advice.